# Recently upgraded application from lo4j1 to log4j2 is not writing logs

Tags: upgrade, log4j2

The application compiles and deploys with only log4j2 jars in the classpath. I can see the log4j.xml config  being intialized and the log files getting created. The server param is -Dlog4j.configurationFile. But the application does not write logs.

But instead, if I place a log4j1  config file in the classpath with the proper param name -Dlog4j.configuration , then the application writes logs.

I am not able to understand how and application decides which version of logfile to consider.

Comment: It's difficult to help you when you don't provide enough detail to reproduce the problem. Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone else can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Your `log4j2.xml` is placed in `classpath` or you are giving the path using `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` VM argument. If it is web application running on server, it would be better to place `log4j2.xml` file in `classpath`. Remember the name of the file should be `log4j2.xml` when you are placing it in `classpath`.

Comment: The log4j2.xml is a server runtime argument Dlog4j.configurationFile .  The log files specified in the appenders are created, except none of the logs are getting written into.   I have empty log files created, but no logs gets written even when the application is running. Instead, if I change the runtime arg to -Dlog4j.configuration and place a log4j1 config file, then I see the logs getting written.